# My inline-block divs are displayed in strange zig-zag pattern

Tags: css

I'm trying to visualise simple commands and their arguments in HTML. Desired output:

[image]

Actual output:

[image]

The code I used:

```css
html {
  background-color: #222;
}

div.script {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.script div.script-command {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 10em;
  min-width:3em;
  
  border: 1px solid #66E239;
  background-color: rgba(102,226,57, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.5 em; 
}
div.script-command p.name {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
div.script-command div.arguments {
  padding: 0.5 em;
  text-align: center;
}
div.script-command div.arguments .argument {
  font-family: "Courier new", consolas;
  color: black;
  font-size:11pt;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 3pt;
  margin: 2pt;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="script">
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">s
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
      <span class="argument">xxx
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">aaa
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">s
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
      <span class="argument">gfdgf
      </span>
      <span class="argument">1000
      </span>
      <span class="argument">5
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">dd\;
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The wrong alignment happens when the `.arguments` div is empty. Why does it happen? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `vertical-align`ment of the inline-block element.

If you want to glance at the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#propdef-vertical-align),

> This shorthand property specifies how an inline-level box is aligned within the line. Values are the same as for its longhand properties, see below.

Since you have the baseline set as default/not specifically set, it will style to the lowest line, and hence by setting it to `top` will align the `inline-block` elements to the *top line*.

```css
html {
  background-color: #222; 
}

div.script {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

div.script div.script-command {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 10em;
  min-width:3em;
   vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid #66E239;
  background-color: rgba(102,226,57, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.5 em; 
}
div.script-command p.name {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
div.script-command div.arguments {
  padding: 0.5 em;
  text-align: center; 
}
div.script-command div.arguments .argument {
  font-family: "Courier new", consolas;
  color: black;
  font-size:11pt;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 3pt;
  margin: 2pt;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="script">
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">s
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
      <span class="argument">xxx
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">aaa
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">s
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
      <span class="argument">gfdgf
      </span>
      <span class="argument">1000
      </span>
      <span class="argument">5
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="script-command">
    <p class="name">dd\;
    </p>
    <hr>
    <div class="arguments">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because it contains explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `vertical-align: top;` on your inline-block elements.

Comment: Wow that was easy! :D

Answer (score 1):

checkout this fix

```
div.script div.script-command {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 10em;
  min-width:3em;
  vertical-align:top;

  border: 1px solid #66E239;
  background-color: rgba(102,226,57, 0.3);
  border-radius: 0.5 em; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jrpq1xe7/